# What is internal memory? Where can I find it?

Tags: ram, cpu-architecture, rom

So today I got to make presentation about RAM ROM and Internal memory, the problem is that internal memory is literally RAM and ROM, I asked my teacher, he said it is and it is not, he also mentioned that there is internal memory in CPU it self or something right that, so any resources about Internal memory and what parts of technology you can find it would be appreciated, also if you could find internal memory in cpu  I would love that because I couldn't find it anywhere!

Comment: "Internal" is an adjective that comes from a classification based on the *location* of the memory. RAM, ROM are terms describing the type of memory. They are orthogonal, you can have an Internal RAM, an Internal ROM, an External RAM, and External ROM, a whatever RAM and a whatever ROM. Simply put, internal means nothing without a description of the architecture. Pretty much like RAM, since there are quite a bit of types of RAM. Your teacher may have meant the registers, the caches, or in general every circuit able to retain a state.

Answer (score 1):

Some microcontrollers come with some internal RAM that's architecturally usable as memory for loads/stores.  (System on chip where external RAM is optional.)  http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/beginner/SRAM.html shows how AVR maps SRAM to the low end of physical address space.  And that the very bottom of physical address space aliases the registers!  (That's unusual, most ISAs don't memory-map the register file.)

But more generally, caches and physical register files are SRAM arrays, so in most CPUs you have internal RAM that's *not* architecturally visible as "memory".